# Facebook not showing thumbnail nor title when sharing an article from wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook, url, share

this last two days, we are encoutring problems with our links: When we want to share a link in facebook, it does not recognize it ( it shows no thmbnail nor the title) .
The  facebook's debugger    (shows the following error:  "URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed." 
and for the URL "http://www.ozap.tv/decouvrez-nouveau-teaser-du-galaxy-s6/"  it gives the canonical  URL "http://www.ozap.tv/SleUZ/decouvrez-nouveau-teaser-du-galaxy-s6/"  which means it adds SIeUZ

for some others the debugger shows the error:   "Could not resolve the hostname into a valid IP address." and the canonical URL is correct.

the article that we published before those two days works fine.

The problem went after having  edited some code.

We are trying to guess the issue of the problem and we want to know if it is related to the DNS, the code or the host server

any help

Cordially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if this is causing the error but in your code, you have duplicate og meta data tags.

```
<!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast WordPress SEO plugin v1.6.3 - https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/ -->
<meta name="description" content="Découvrez le nouveau teaser du Galaxy S6 !"/>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.ozap.tv/decouvrez-nouveau-teaser-du-galaxy-s6/" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="fr_FR" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Découvrez le nouveau teaser du Galaxy S6 !" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Découvrez le nouveau teaser du Galaxy S6 !" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.ozap.tv/decouvrez-nouveau-teaser-du-galaxy-s6/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Ozap" />
<meta property="article:section" content="Actualités" />
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2015-02-19T09:31:40+00:00" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.ozap.tv/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/next-galaxy-charging.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://images.frandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/s6-puissance-teaser-630x232.png" />
<!-- / Yoast WordPress SEO plugin. -->
```

and

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Ozap" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.ozap.tv/decouvrez-nouveau-teaser-du-galaxy-s6/" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Découvrez le nouveau teaser du Galaxy S6 !" />
<meta property="og:description" content="La vague de teasing orchestrée la semaine dernière par Samsung évoquait les capacités photo du futur Galaxy (S6) dont l’annonce est prévue au prochain Mobile World Congress. Cette semaine, le Coréen c" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.ozap.tv/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/next-galaxy-charging.jpg" />
```

This could confuse Facebook as this is where Facebook gets the information from.

*Edit

Another strange thing that I picked up is the following redirect:

Checked link: http://www.ozap.tv/decouvrez-nouveau-teaser-du-galaxy-s6/

Type of redirect: 302 Found
Redirected to: http://www.ozap.tv/QYWSZ/decouvrez-nouveau-teaser-du-galaxy-s6/

Answer (score 0):

i reviewed the code in wordpress

the first bloc of code is written by Yoast SEO plugin

the second one is written by a function in the file function.php

Now that i've desabled the Yoast SEO plugin, i can share articles after using the debugger tool. i put the URL of the article and i click "Fetch new scrape information". 
After desabling Yoast SEO, the problem of redirecting is resolved, as it seems.

Is that a problem in the cach of  facebook?

Answer (score 0):

i'm returning to that issue again. I need to have the Yoast SEO plugin and i need to use facebook widget too, so i have to solve the issue differently. i'm wondering if i delete the function i was talking about from the file "function.php", and if i install those widget and plugin again, would i encouter the same issue again (duplacating the ogtags)

```
  function dp_fb_ogtags(){
            $site_name = esc_attr(get_option('blogname'));
            $type = is_front_page() ? 'website' : 'article';
            $url = get_permalink();
            $title = wp_title( '|', false, 'right' );
            $desc = dp_get_doc_desc();
            $image = '';
            $admins = '';

            // Get image
                if (is_singular()) {
                    global $post;

                    // Get image by feature image
                    $image = dp_thumb_url('large', false, $post->ID);

                    // Get image from post attachments
                    if(empty($image) && $images = get_children('post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent='.$post->ID))
                        if (is_array($images) && !empty($images))
                            $image = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url(current($images)->ID);

                    // Get first image from post content
                    if(empty($image) && preg_match('/<img[^>]*src=([\'"])(.*?)\\1/i', $post->post_content, $matches))
                        $image = $matches[2];
                }



            // Generate meta tags
            $nl = "\n";
            $tags = '';
            $tags .= '<meta property="og:site_name" content="'.$site_name.'" />'.$nl;
            $tags .= '<meta property="og:type" content="'.$type.'" />'.$nl;
            $tags .= '<meta property="og:url" content="'.$url.'" />'.$nl;
            if($title)
                $tags .= '<meta property="og:title" content="'.$title.'" />'.$nl;
            if($desc)
                $tags .= '<meta property="og:description" content="'.  esc_attr($desc).'" />'.$nl;
            if($image)
                $tags .= '<meta property="og:image" content="'.$image.'" />'.$nl;
            if($admins)
                $tags .= '<meta property="fb:admins" content="'.esc_attr($admins).'" />'.$nl;

            echo $tags;//*/
        }
```